# Replace Grease Pencil object with a mesh object and vice versa

Tags: python, objects, grease-pencil, linked-data

I am sketching an environment scene, wherein I want to draw the location for trees as a Grease Pencil object. So that I can create a more appropriate floor plan design. When I am done sketching, I want to replace the Grease Pencil objects with the actual tree meshes. So I was wondering, considering I keep the object origins in-tact by duplicating the Grease Pencil trees, can I replace them with the mesh object? And the other way around, can I also replace a mesh with a Grease Pencil object?
[image]

The Link/ Transfer data menu pop-up (Ctrl+L) doesn't allow me to link the object data between different object types.

If this is possible with a script that can be placed in the Ctrl+L menu that would also be fine with me.

[image]

Comment: also might be worth looking into geometry node. Whilst you can't make one on GP objects, by converting GP to curve then plugging it into `curve to mesh` > `merge by distance` > `instance on points` you would end up with a similar result

Comment: @wilks GN is actually a great idea ! While you can't add GN modifiers to grease pencil objects, you can instance GPs inside a GN modifier on a mesh object. Using a switch node to switch between the two at runtime, you wouldn't even have a destructive behaviour.

Comment: @Gorgious right, sounds like an even better idea, but I don't see how you'd get any useful position data from the GP object without converting it beforehand, like, is there a node that let's you convert GP to curve/mesh?

Comment: Interesting idea, though at this point GN doesn't seem to be mature enough to do this effectively, like the script below does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change an object's data type once it has been created. Here's a suggestion that will create new objects and copy the data in the same location as the selected objects.

[image]

```
import bpy


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Replace Selected By Active"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    delete_selected: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=True, name="Delete Selected")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return len(context.selected_objects) > 1

    def execute(self, context):
        source = context.active_object
        for obj in context.selected_objects:
            if obj == source:
                continue
            new = bpy.data.objects.new(name=source.name, object_data=source.data)
            source.users_collection[0].objects.link(new)
            new.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world
            # If you don't want the new objects to inherit scale & rotation, use this :
            # new.location = obj.location
            if self.delete_selected:
                bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
            new.select_set(True)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text=SimpleOperator.bl_label)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_make_links.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_make_links.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I managed to make this into an addon myself :)
But I feel like you should be the one to distribute it.

Comment: @Hologram Please do ! I don't mind at all, I already have a bunch on my plate ;) Cheers